# Javascript : finding a specific previous element on list and adding class

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have a list like this.

[image]

Inside each .list item there is a html button :

```
<div class="list">
<button>.list</button>
</div>
```

Also, each item can be inside a `.bloc` element

[image]

```
  <div class="list"><button>.list</button></div>
  <div class=bloc>
    <div class="list"><button>.list</button></div>
  </div>
```

When I click on the button, I would like the previous .list item to have the .active class like so :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Well it’s pretty easy with jquery and i've done that, it’s work pretty well :

```
$('.list button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.list').prev('.list').addClass('active');
});
```

**BUT** i have some specific cases :
Sometimes the list items **can be hidden** and a list with hidden class can’t have .active class :

[image]

[image]

Or more complicated. You have to go up on each item one by one and put the active class to the first which does not have the hidden class :

[image]

[image]

I did the mechanics for items **without class hidden**, but I'm afraid I'm going in the wrong direction because the number of cases is getting bigger and bigger. Ain't there a smarter way ? :o

```
  $('.list button').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).closest('.list').prev().length === 0) {
      if ($(this).closest('.bloc').length) {
        $(this).closest('.bloc').prev('.list').addClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.bloc').prev('.bloc').find('.list:last-child').addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.list').next('.list').addClass('active');
      }
    }

    if ($(this).closest('.list').prev('.bloc').length) {
      $(this).closest('.list').prev('.bloc').find('.list:last-child').addClass('active');
    }
    $(this).closest('.list').prev('.list').addClass('active'); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `.closest` `.prev` and `.next` you can use the [overload](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) to `.index` which will give you the index within an existing collection.

```
var idx = collection.index(element);
```

- select all your .list items into a jquery object/collection
- when clicking get the index *within that collection*
- subtract 1 to get the previous .list item within that collection

The basic scenarios are covered with `$(".list")` :

```js
// collate the list first
var list = $(".list");

// add click handler
list.click(function() {
    // confirm there are no duplicates
    // comapred with $(this).index() which is the index within the parent
    console.log(list.index(this), $(this).index())
    
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    
    var idx = list.index(this);
    if (idx > 0)
        list.eq(idx-1).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.list { border:1px solid #CCC; height: 20px; }
.bloc { border:1px solid #444; padding: 5px; }
.active { border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>

  <div class='bloc'>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='list'></div>
  <div class='list'></div>

</div>
```

All the other use-cases are then just a case of providing the correct selector up-front, with otherwise exactly the same code

```
var list = $(".wrapper>.bloc:not(.hidden)>.list:not(.hidden),.wrapper>.list:not(.hidden)");
```

I've tried to recreate some of your scenarios, but if there's one that's missing, please comment and I'll ensure it fits (within the remit of the question).

Giving:

```js
var list = $(".wrapper>.bloc:not(.hidden)>.list:not(.hidden),.wrapper>.list:not(.hidden)")
list.click(function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    var idx = list.index(this);
    if (idx > 0)
        list.eq(idx-1).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.list { border:1px solid #CCC; height: 20px; }
.bloc { border:1px solid #444; padding: 5px; }
.active { border:1px solid red; }
.hidden { background-color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='bloc'>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='list hidden'></div>
  <div class='bloc'>
    <div class='list hidden'></div>
    <div class='list hidden'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='list'></div>
  <div class='bloc'>
    <div class='list hidden'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='list'></div>
  <div class='list'></div>
  <div class='bloc hidden'>
    <div class='list'></div>
    <div class='list'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='list'></div>
  <div class='list'></div>
</div>
```